# JQuery unbind "filtered" result vs query selector result

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

After setting up an event listener for e.g. the class 'rule1' on an input
i.e `<input type="checkbox" class="rule1">`

```
$('[class*=rule]').filter(function() {
    return /rule[0-9]+/.test($(this).attr('class'));
}).each(function() {
    $(this).bind('click', function() { limitRule(this) });
});
```

It seems the only way I can unbind this listener is by doing the exact same snippet and unbinding

```
$('[class*=rule]').filter(function() {
    return /rule[0-9]+/.test($(this).attr('class'));
}).each(function() {
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

But why is it this doesnt work?

```
$('.edit_contact_label input').unbind('click');
```

The query matches the same inputs and the resultset contain the same elements, but the original listener is still called.

For reference, html might resemble:

```
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Option 1
    <label class="edit_contact_label">
        Main Contact <input type="checkbox" name="contact1n" id="contact1" value="1" style="" class=" rule1 standard ">
    </label>
</h4>
...
<h4>Option 2
    <label class="edit_contact_label">
        Main Contact <input type="checkbox" name="contact2" id="contact2" value="1" style="" class=" rule1 standard ">
    </label>
</h4>
...
<h4>Option 3
    <label class="edit_contact_label">
        Main Contact <input type="checkbox" name="contact3" id="contact3" value="1" style="" class=" rule1 standard ">
    </label>
</h4>
...
```

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine for unbinding clicks. https://jsfiddle.net/nf6tt4r3/ Show us a [mcve] demonstrating your actual problem - its not what you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You must use `.each()` since you bound the listeners to each jQuery object individually, but</s> You don't necessarily have to use the same `.filter()` function to get the jQuery selection, as long as you manage to select all the same elements:

```js
$('[class*=rule]').filter(function() {
  return /rule[0-9]+/.test($(this).attr('class'));
}).each(function() {
  $(this).bind('click', function() {
    // notice this will never get called
    alert(this)
  });
});

$('.edit_contact_label input').unbind('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Option 1
  <label class="edit_contact_label">
        Main Contact <input type="checkbox" name="contact1n" id="contact1" value="1" style="" class=" rule1 standard ">
    </label>
</h4>
<h4>Option 2
  <label class="edit_contact_label">
        Main Contact <input type="checkbox" name="contact2" id="contact2" value="1" style="" class=" rule1 standard ">
    </label>
</h4>
<h4>Option 3
  <label class="edit_contact_label">
        Main Contact <input type="checkbox" name="contact3" id="contact3" value="1" style="" class=" rule1 standard ">
    </label>
</h4>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I had tried that approach while writing this question up, if someone else can confirm this does indeed work - I'll assume there is something else conflicting in my js.

Comment: @mr12086 when you run this snippet, it works correctly. What version of jQuery are you using? That's extremely relevant. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44889164/edit) your question to include that information, and don't blame answerers for operating on incomplete information when you don't produce a [mcve].

Comment: I haven't blamed the answer, in fact I have stated it could be my end.. Don't jump on the defensive.. Indeed running it through jsfiddle, it should work as you stated.

Comment: Running unbind on the collection before each appears to work fine too, so there is something else in my code that is not working, but you may want to update the answer as it isn't correct.

Comment: @mr12086 again, until you produce a [mcve], this _is_ the correct answer, given your incomplete information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44889164/edit) your question to provide proof that this answer does not work for you.

Comment: No matter the version of JQuery used, you do not need to run unbind on each jquery object separately,  it works fine on a collection.

Comment: @mr12086 that is corrrected as you can see, but your statement `there is something else in my code that is not working` is completely irrelevant to this question, unless you provide proof that this alone is not sufficient.

Comment: No no, I was stating that the problem is outside the scope of this answer/question,  this answer is correct for intents and purposes.